# Why does String.split treat the start and end part of a string differently?

Tags: java, string, split

Example:

```
String s = ":a:b:c:";
s.split(":");
// Output: [, a, b, c]
```

From the Java Doc:

`The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string.`

Why is the starting empty string considered where the ending empty string is not?
The starting empty string terminates by ":" and the ending empty string terminates by the end of the string. So both should be listed, should they not?

Comment: `split` really takes a regular expression.. so just `:` may not be ideal in your case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you don't supply a `limit`, the [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method doesn't return trailing empty matches.  To quote the Javadocs:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

If you use the 2-parameter version of [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)), then pass in a negative limit and the size of the returned array won't be restricted; you'll get trailing empty strings.

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length.

Here I think the Javadocs are referring to `limit` when they say `n`.

Answer (score 2):

It behaves as defined [in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). To also get the trailing empty string, you can use [the other split method, that takes two arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
s.split(":", -1);
// Output: [, a, b, c, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the javadocs:

```
 Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
```

.split also supports a second parameter (limit), which changes the default behavior, as shown below:

```
String s = ":a:b:c:";
s.split(":", 0); //"Default" Split behaviour -->  [, a, b, c]
s.split(":", 1); //Array length == 1 --> [:a:b:c:]
s.split(":", 2); //Array length ==  2 --> [, a:b:c:]
s.split(":", 3); //Array length == 3 --> [, a, b:c:]
s.split(":", -1); //Any length. Trailling empty spaces are not ommited --> [, a, b, c, ]
```

Just as a side note, [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides a lot of classes to speed up development in Java, such as Splitter, which could suit your needs:

```
private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on(':')
   .trimResults()
   .omitEmptyStrings();

//returns ["a", "b", "c"]
SPLITTER.split(":a:b::::c:::")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this method  **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.
you can get detail idea from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)